# I git cloned a repo and I cannot run it on localhost because missing gem and cannot bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

I git cloned a repo. I cannot run it on localhost with rails server because terminal says

> Could not find activesupport-4.2.5 in any of the sources Run `bundle
>   install` to install missing gems.

When I run bundle install, I get

> An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before
>   bundling.

I have rails 4.2.3, and the repo's Gemfile has  gem 'rails', '4.2.5'. I don't know if this matter

Answer (score 3):

Gem `pg` is Postgres driver, it only can be installed, if corresponding headers and libraries are present and can be accessed.

Most probably just installing postgres will fix it. If you're on a Mac with homebrew - `brew install postgresql`

Answer (score 1):

Install postgresql.

Remove Gemfile.lock

Add **gem 'pg'** in your gemfile

execute **bundle install**

Answer (score 0):

**1:** Remove Gemfile.lock  if Gemgile.lock present in your project

**2:** add **`gem 'pg'`**  # in Gemfile

**3:** Run **`bundle install`**

Hope this help you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Run
`sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -v '1.18.4'`

Now try running `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of @Chakreshwar Sharma and @Vinay's answers to get this working for the metasploit-framework.

1. Remove Gemfile.lock
2. Add **gem 'pg'** in your gemfile
3. Run **apt-cache search postgresql-server-dev**
4. **apt-get update && apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.5** # Check your version
5. **bundle install --no-deployment**

To be honest, I think you could just run:

1. **apt-cache search postgresql-server-dev**
2. **apt-cache search postgresql-server-dev-9.5**
3. **bundle install**

...and you can avoid messing with the Gemfile, but I didn't get to verify it since mine started working after I made the adjustments.